# Netbeans project integration with different frameworks

Tags: eclipse, persistence, integration, netbeans-6.9

We work as a third party with
 `MVC traditional framework with oracle 11g (no hibernate)` with login.jsp page to enter the systems

The main company took the 
`struts2 and spring and hibernate frameworks approach also with oracle 11g`
 and they have thier login.jsp

When we integrated our work together the **login.jsp** approved the is the last one due to privileges issues (from the main company) although they are too similar but its programmed with hibernate,struts,spring.

There is one problem occurred that their **login.jsp** page gives an error (**below**)

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.uts.entities.appsecurity.Users**

The details is too long so i stored it in jsfiddle just for viewing...
[The error](http://jsfiddle.net/sssonline2/ptN69/)

Now i should mention when integration i added some extra files .xml from the main company to work with theire framework in addition to their actual work:

1)libraries
2)persistence.xml
3)struts.xml
4)validators.xml
5)applicationContext.xml

Now if i enter the login.jsp i used to use in development it works but not the main company login.jsp we are looking for a solution for this !
the deploy does not give an error and when pressing login apachetomcat output does not give an error , it just redirect to error page on `http://localhost:8084/HumanResources_2/presentation/securityAction.action`

- The main company login

`http://localhost:8084/HumanResources_2/presentation/Login.jsp`

- Our(my) login

`http://localhost:8084/HumanResources_2/login.jsp`

Another thing the login page of the main company the text appearing as **`undefined`** all of them.

[image: Main company login]

i don`t know what causing this it works before integration , note that the main company using **Eclipse** am ready for any thing i can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was a BUG in netbeans
look at the photo there is line i must remove to make it work the selected one

[image: persistence.xml code view]

the check when true the above line added automatically am not sure why but it solved it

[image: persistence.xml design view]